# Skip mounting node_modules folder inside docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, node-modules, docker-volume

I have a node js application which is run inside docker.

In Dockerfile, I create the app and move my local code into it.

```
# Dockerfile

FROM node:8.6.0

WORKDIR /app

# Copying app
COPY . /app

# Executing test script
RUN scripts/pre-build.sh
```

My directory structure is as.

> - scripts
> - node_modules
> - src
>
>   - execute
>   - independent_module
>
>     - shared_module_for_some_task

I have an independent module folder inside src which is linked to `node_modules` folder through `npm link`. When I run `npm link` for a package a local `node_modules` is created for the package(shared_module_for_some_task).

While running the image, I mount the local changes in src to the src inside the container. This overrides the `node_modules` folder created locally for the package, as there is no node_modules in local(it is created on docker build when `npm link` is executed).

I have tried creating an empty node_modules folder under this `shared_module_for_some_task`, but it didn't work.

The folder is overridden or changes to blank as it is in local.
This works well when I run the image without mounting the directory.

Is there any way to achieve this. Please suggest.

**Adding it in .dockerignore also does not work**

**I do not want to use docker-compose.yml file with volume to hide the mount for node_modules.**